# Python telethon Разбор entity

Tags: python, telethon

получил entity чата:

```
ChatFull(
    full_chat=ChannelFull(
        id=1116621739,
        about='DCx - Managed Global Payment Blockchain',
        read_inbox_max_id=0,
        read_outbox_max_id=0,
        unread_count=0,
        chat_photo=Photo(
            id=1633033170115995569,
            access_hash=8984998890296788523,
            date=datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 27, 21, 2, 24, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
            sizes=[
                PhotoSize(
                    type='a',
                    location=FileLocation(
                        dc_id=4,
                        volume_id=439017094,
                        local_id=43782,
                        secret=-8457972351196598110
                    ),
                    w=160,
                    h=160,
                    size=11022
                ),
                PhotoSize(
                    type='b',
                    location=FileLocation(
                        dc_id=4,
                        volume_id=439017094,
                        local_id=43783,
                        secret=2676694934137458113
                    ),
                    w=320,
                    h=320,
                    size=23926
                ),
                PhotoSize(
                    type='c',
                    location=FileLocation(
                        dc_id=4,
                        volume_id=439017094,
                        local_id=43784,
                        secret=-7123110236713885533
                    ),
                    w=640,
                    h=640,
                    size=69692
                ),
            ],
            has_stickers=False
        ),
        notify_settings=PeerNotifySettings(
            show_previews=None,
            silent=None,
            mute_until=None,
            sound=None
        ),
        exported_invite=ChatInviteEmpty(
        ),
        bot_info=[
        ],
        can_view_participants=False,
        can_set_username=False,
        can_set_stickers=False,
        hidden_prehistory=False,
        participants_count=10,
        admins_count=None,
        kicked_count=None,
        banned_count=None,
        migrated_from_chat_id=None,
        migrated_from_max_id=None,
        pinned_msg_id=None,
        stickerset=None,
        available_min_id=None
    ),
    chats=[
        Channel(
            id=1116621739,
            title='DCX Tokensale',
            photo=ChatPhoto(
                photo_small=FileLocation(
                    dc_id=4,
                    volume_id=439017094,
                    local_id=43782,
                    secret=-8457972351196598110
                ),
                photo_big=FileLocation(
                    dc_id=4,
                    volume_id=439017094,
                    local_id=43784,
                    secret=-7123110236713885533
                )
            ),
            date=datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 6, 2, 26, 5, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
            version=0,
            creator=False,
            left=True,
            editor=False,
            broadcast=True,
            verified=False,
            megagroup=False,
            restricted=False,
            democracy=False,
            signatures=False,
            min=False,
            access_hash=4110269745224753542,
            username='dcxpblockchain',
            restriction_reason=None,
            admin_rights=None,
            banned_rights=None,
            participants_count=None
        ),
    ],
    users=[
    ]
)
```

Как получить доступ к полям? На сайте библиотеки не нашел примеров. Не вручную же разбирать.

Пытался так:

```
print(entity["full_chat"])
```

Выкидывает ошибку:

```
future: <Task finished coro=<get_entity() done, defined at D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py:53> exception=TypeError("'ChatFull' object is not subscriptable")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 84, in get_entity
    await parse_entity(result)
  File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 51, in parse_entity
    print(await entity["full_chat"])
TypeError: 'ChatFull' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: А какой тип у `entity`? Ошибка говорит что у этой сущности оператор `[]` не поддерживается

Comment: @gil9red <class 'telethon.tl.types.messages.ChatFull'>

Comment: @gil9red https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/constructors/messages/chat_full.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно получить описание так:

```
print(entity.full_chat.id)
```